# How to easily add SharePoint Types to VS Code globally?

Tags: csom, jsom, spfx, typescript

It is easy to add Types of CSOM to VS Code by using npm install @types/sharepoint --save in a project folder.

However, is it possible to use it globally so I don't need to add it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually quite simple, just open the command prompt and type the below command:

```
npm i @types/sharepoint -g
```

Now this is installed globally on your machine.

After that, next time you create a new project, just add below line in the `package.json` file.

```
"@types/sharepoint": "2013.1.1"
```

This will automatically add the typings in your project next time you press `npm i`.